# Camera trace recording in Paraview

Tags: python, paraview

I use Paraview 5.8.1 but my question holds for older versions.

I want to generate a Python script to automate my visualizations. I use the "trace recorder" tool which records the actions I do in the GUI and translate them into
the Python script that would lead to the same result.

However this tool does not record everything : for instance camera position or orientation axes size modications are not translated whereas the Python functions to hold this do exist.

Is there any way to get the trace recorder to record everything ?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: nope.

ParaView use a property mechanism. Lot of things are properties (filter parameters, color setting, ...) and are available for record. But camera are not. When the trace stops, an internal hook adds the last camera in the trace.

You can use this as a Macro to add the current Camera in the trace:

```
from paraview import simple
from paraview import smtrace

smtrace.Trace.get_accessor(simple.GetActiveView())
camera_trace = smtrace.SaveCameras.get_trace(None)
if camera_trace:
    a = smtrace.Trace.Output.append_separated(
            "#### saving camera placements for all active views")
    a = smtrace.Trace.Output.append_separated(camera_trace)
```

That said, I'm not sure to see a use case ... If you want to see an animation of your scene, you cannot use the Trace mechanism but you should use the Animation View instead.

Comment: Thank you. If the last camera position is added at the end of the trace, I can make use of it. smtrace.Trace
Your script is interesting, but line 7 raise an error. `smtrace.Trace.Outpur` returns None

Comment: you should start the trace before using this script